# actionscript facebook Login fails with Error #2032: Stream Error. on Mobile device

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, apache-flex, facebook-actionscript-api

I'm trying to login with my facebook account in a flex mobile application.

The steps for my scenario are:

1. push the facebook login button
2. the facebook login pop-up appears
3. User types username and password, hits login button.

   My code:

   ```
    public function performLogin():void
   {
       var facebookWebView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
       facebookWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle (0,0, m_stage.width, m_stage.height);

       FacebookMobile.login(loginCallback ,m_stage, m_appPermissions, facebookWebView)
   }


       private function loginCallback(success:Object, fail:Object):void
   {
    if (success) // using the Flex Emulator a success object is returned and everyting works as it should
       {
           var session:FacebookSession = success as FacebookSession;
           //save access token
           PersistanceMechanism.instance.add(sAccessToken, session.accessToken);

           //forward to success view
           if (m_successView != null)
              m_viewNavigator.pushView(m_successView);
           return;
       }
   ```

Everything works fine with the Flex Emulator and loginCallback contains a correct "success" object.

However, when testing this on my Galaxy SIII the callback gets a fail object instead with the following message:

```
       Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me?access%5Ftoken=AAAFA7Xkx1wwBAC7ZAQmrvHcZBwYv5ZBLcUvZClaGSrpNzVXRA1HsgQShIOQCOqy2tGAHVHKTbwH8taTrS8XBtVSN4JxW6ZAH8Az5ldJiMiwZDZD
```

Can you please tell me what is the cause for this and why is this issue reproducible only on a real mobile device?

Thank you

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a problem with the Adobe AIR version. Updated to the latest version and works.